# How To Convert An Order Subtotal Value To Cents

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I am trying to pass my order subtotal to a third-party for revenue tracking on an optimization system.

However, the system needs the number in cents.  How can I get my value, which is outputted as this `{{$cart.subtotal}}`

Converted within the script to multiply by 100 and display results?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.optimizely = window.optimizely || [];
    window.optimizely.push(['trackEvent', 'PURCHASE',{{$cart.subtotal}}]);

</script>
```

If someone purchased $29.99 above, it would be 29.99, but I need it to show 2999

Sorry, I'm just starting to learn javascript

Answer (score 2):

If the value is a string you can remove the decimal place:

```
$cart.subtotal.replace('.','')
```

But mulitplying by 100 should do.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.optimizely = window.optimizely || [];
    window.optimizely.push(['trackEvent', 'PURCHASE',{{$cart.subtotal*100}}]);

</script>
```